# How to create an iterator that yields elements of a collection specified by a list of indices in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

Is there a concise way to iterate over a vector using a given list of indices? I have code that looks similar to this:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Create a vector
    let v = vec![0.1, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 7.8];

    // Create a series of indices
    let i = vec![3, 4, 2, 1];

    // Iterate over the elements in v in the order specified by each index in i
    for j in &i {
        println!("{}", v[*j]);
    }
}
```

I'd like to modify it so that I loop directly over elements in `v` rather than having to loop over the indices in `i`.  Basically, something that looks similar to `for x in vs[i]`.

Comment: There's nothing built in, but you could create your own iterator that does it.

Comment: How about `for j in i.iter().map(|&i| v[i]) {}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility:

```
i.iter().map(|idx| v[*idx])
```

as in:

```
fn main() {
    // Create a vector
    let v = vec![0.1, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 7.8];

    // Create a series of indices
    let i = vec![3, 4, 2, 1];

    // Iterate over the elements in v in the order specified by i
    for j in i.iter().map(|idx| v[*idx]) {
        println!("{}", j);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely better than the 60 lines of code that it took to define an appropriate iterator.  It reverses the ordering of indexing to values that I had thought, but works well.  Thanks!